# Problem with multiprocessing in Python writing into csv

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I created a function which takes a date as an argument and writes produced output into csv. If I run multiprocessing Pool with e.g. 28 tasks, and I have a list of 100 dates, then the last 72 rows in the output csv file are twice longer than they should be (just a joined repetition of last 72 rows).

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing

#Load the data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', low_memory=False)
list_s = df.date.unique()
def funk(date):
    ...
    # for each date in df.date.unique() do stuff which gives sample dataframe
    # as an output

    return sample

# list_s is a list of dates I want to calculate function funk for   

def mp_handler():
# 28 is a number of processes I want to run
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(28)
    for result in p.imap(funk, list_s[0:100]):
        result.to_csv('crsp_full.csv', mode='a')


if __name__=='__main__':
    mp_handler()
```

And the output looks like this:

```
date,port_ret_1,port_ret_2
2010-03-05,0.0,0.002
date,port_ret_1,port_ret_2
2010-02-12,-0.001727,0.009139189315

...
# and after first 28 rows like this
date,port_ret_1,port_ret_2,port_ret_1,port_ret_2
2010-03-03,0.002045,0.00045092025,0.002045,0.00045092025
date,port_ret_1,port_ret_2,port_ret_1,port_ret_2
2010-03-15,-0.006055,-0.00188451972,-0.006055,-0.00188451972
```

I tried to insert `lock()` into the `funk()`, but it yielded the same results, just took more time to implement. Any ideas how to fix it?

**Edit**. `funk` looks like this. `e` is equivalent to date.

```
def funk(e):
    block = pd.DataFrame()
    i = s_list.index(e)
    if i > 19:
        ran = s_list[i-19:i+6]
        ran0 = s_list[i-19:i+1]
        # print ran0
        piv = df.pivot(index='date', columns='permno', values='date')
        # Drop the stocks which do not have returns for the given time window and make the list of suitable stocks
        s = list(piv.loc[ran].dropna(axis=1).columns)
        sample = df[df['permno'].isin(s)]
        sample = sample.loc[ran]
        permno = ['10001', '93422']
        sample = sample[sample['permno'].isin(permno)]
        # print sample.index.unique()
        # get past 20 days returns in additional 20 columns
        for i in range(0, 20):
            sample['r_{}'.format(i)] = sample.groupby('permno')['ret'].shift(i)
        #merge dataset with betas
        sample = pd.merge(sample, betas_aug, left_index=True, right_index=True)
        sample['ex_ret'] = 0

        # calculate expected return
        for i in range(0,20):
            sample['ex_ret'] += sample['ma_beta_{}'.format(i)]*sample['r_{}'.format(i)]
        # print(sample)
        # define a stock into two legs based on expected return
        sample['sign'] = sample['ex_ret'].apply(lambda x: -1 if x<0 else 1)
        # workaround for short leg, multiply returns by -1
        sample['abs_ex_ret'] = sample['ex_ret']*sample['sign']
        # create 5 columns for future realised 5 days returns (multiplied by -1 for short leg)
        for i in range(1,6):
            sample['rp_{}'.format(i)] = sample.groupby(['permno'])['ret'].shift(-i)
            sample['rp_{}'.format(i)] = sample['rp_{}'.format(i)]*sample['sign']
        sample = sample.reset_index(drop=True)
        sample['w_0'] = sample['abs_ex_ret'].div(sample.groupby(['date'])['abs_ex_ret'].transform('sum'))
        for i in range(1, 5):
            sample['w_{}'.format(i)] = sample['w_{}'.format(i-1)]*(1+sample['rp_{}'.format(i)])
        sample = sample.dropna(how='any')
        for k in range(0,20):
            sample.drop(columns = ['ma_beta_{}'.format(k), 'r_{}'.format(k)])
        for k in range(1, 6):
            sample['port_ret_{}'.format(k)] = sample['w_{}'.format(k-1)]*sample['rp_{}'.format(k)]
            q = ['port_ret_{}'.format(k)]
            list_names.extend(q)
        block = sample.groupby('date')[list_names].sum().copy()
    return block
```

Comment: why are you writing to a file using multiprocessing, pretty sure there will be data races in all situations since simple csvs don’t support features like this afaik

Comment: @aws_apprentice was also my first thought, but OP is actually only writing to the file from the main process (unless funk also writes something). So that's not it. My bet is that there is a scoping problem within funk and somehow the df grows from one function call to the next.

Comment: Well, I was trying to append these dataframes to a global dataframe, and after that write it into csv, but at some point of time, there was a mismatch between number of columns of the global df and `result`. Meaning that the global(updated) dataframe looked like the first part of the example file given above, and idk why `result` dataframe looked like the second part of the output csv file (with doubled number of columns)

Comment: @swenzel I will check my function and edit the question with more detailed code

Comment: Try `sample = df[df['permno'].isin(s)].copy()`. And as @stovfl points out, you should better use `result.to_csv('crsp_full.csv', mode='a', header=False)` except for the first one.

Comment: @stovfl it is still a valid `csv`, just with mixed datatypes. I did it to make sure it doubles the dataframe. @swenzel `copy` does not help. If I change number of processes to 60 e.g. then it correctly writes first 60 dataframes and then messes up the rest.

Comment: Ah, sorry... `list_names` is your problem. It comes from an outer scope and you keep extending it but you do not clear it somewhere.

Comment: Just found a mistake! @swenzel you were write, the dataframe used already existing `list_names` from previous processes and it was extending it again in the last lines. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, It doesn't help much to raise the number of processes above the number of virtual cores of your machine. Or do you have 60 cores?

Comment: @swenzel I am using university HPC, so I can have 60 cores.Though still trying to understand if I can increase RAM for each task, or it is restricted by mem_per_core.